# A canonical question for installing Nvidia GPU drivers?

Tags: discussion, support

Do we have a canonical question for this right now?

Since `nvidia-common` became `nvidia-xxx` I am having a hard time finding a good Q&A for it.

I saw [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/843845/how-to-change-defualt-graphic-card-to-nvidia-graphic-card/843862#843862); it is basically "How do I install Nvidia drivers?". Do we have a question for this?

If not, please suggest some, as this is a common question. They must be well written, well answered and NOT suggesting `nvidia-common` or `bumblebee`. If no suitable question exists, should we consider creating one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I use:

- [How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers)

It's currently losing the google juice to this question though: [How do I install the Nvidia driver for a GeForce GT 630](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451221/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-driver-for-a-geforce-gt-630)

Maybe we should consider a merge? Also I'm wondering if trimming down the accepted answer would help, it's almost too overwhelming!

Comment: I vote for a merge and then split up the question/answer like [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc)...

Comment: I like the answers on the first one too and the title. I agree the answer perhaps goes a bit far, a simple one would be good along side it. Forgive my ignorance but when `merging`, does that mean to take answers from one post and add them to another? I would support that for sure, consolidating all the info in one place.

Comment: Yes, a merge would include all the answers.

Comment: I am going to accept this because that first link is what I am going to use for now. Hopefully we will get that merge at some point soon.

Answer (score 1):

I think we need a new one, maybe a CW, that gets updated periodically to reflect current drivers, or one that is structured so as to be mostly future-proof.

The Q&A should include:

- The difference between the Nouveau and Proprietary drivers
- The difference among the different versions for the Proprietary drivers
- A mention of the `graphics-drivers` PPA, and how it has more up-to-date drivers
- Installation instructions using `apt-get`
- (The more complex) installation instructions for installing from the website
- A link to my Q&A (totally not a shameless plug), about fixing problems after installation.
- A link to the login loop Q&A
- Some other basic troubleshooting

I don't know if the subjects should be split into different answers or just grouped under headers.

Basically, I think we should deliberately make a complete Q&A, covering pretty much all we can cover about NVIDIA. The current Q&As are outdated and not really complete. If we pruposely make a new one, I think it'll last a lot longer.

Comment: I would be for writing a new question for this, to include a lot more answers but I think we should take existing answers and add them to that question. There are some great answers around and they deserve votes but I would support a detailed question on this for duping. against.

Comment: @MarkKirby I agree that good answers should get credit, but they tend to become outdated, and they're not all in one place. Maybe we give related links in the relevant sections of a constructed answer.

Comment: You've pretty much described Luis' answer in the existing question!